Javascript, Call a nested function from outside the function or call it from inside another function
Is it possible to call a function that is nested inside a function from either outside of the original function or from inside another function?
So in the example when the func_1 is called the first time it calls the nested_func_1 and returns a value;
In the second function (func_2) is it possible to call the nested_func_1 that is nested inside func_1 and return a value?
Finally is it possible to call nested_fun_1 from outside any function and return a value?
Thanks.


    function func_1(){
        function nested_func_1(a){
            console.log("<br/> NESTED READ");
            a = a * 2;
            return a;
        };
        b = nested_func_1(23);
        return b;
    };
    
    function func_2(){
        // Call function nested_func_1 that is 
        // nested inside func_1 and return value;
        b = nested_func_1(32);
        return b;
    };
    
    a = func_1();
    console.log("AAA "+a);
    
    // CALL THE NESTED FUNCTION - nested_func_1 - 
    // FROM inside func_2 and return result;
    a = func_2();
    console.log("BBB "+a);
    
    // CALL THE NESTED FUNC from 
    // outside both functions;
    b = nested_funct_1(23);
    console.log(b);




No. Scope "protects" local symbols. Also, it kind-of doesn't make sense anyway, because the "nested" function only exists when the outer function is called.

don't nest the function inside another functon if you need it outside, it's as simple as that.

You can make it so that you can call internal functions from outside.
To do this, you need to modify the code a little and declare the internal functions as your own properties of the function:


function func_1() {
  // custom properties. name_fn.userProperties
  func_1.nested_func_1 = function(a) {
    console.log("<br/> NESTED READ");
    a = a * 2;
    return a;
  }
  return func_1.nested_func_1(23);
}

function func_2() {
  // take properties from func_1
  const b = func_1.nested_func_1(32);
  return b;
}

const a = func_1(); // first call func_1
console.log("AAA " + a);

const b = func_2(); // first call func_2
console.log("BBB " + b);

const c = func_1.nested_func_1(45);
console.log('CCC', c);



An important condition for this is that the visibility of the user-defined properties of the function appears only after the function has been called at least 1 time.
That is, if you refer to func_1.nested_func_1 before the first call of func_1(), then we get undefined
You can also expand the properties of functions at any time


function func_1() {
  console.log('run');
}

func_1();

func_1.newFn = function(d) {
  return d ** 2;
}

console.log(func_1.newFn(5));



This also works for arrow functions


const arrowFn = () => {
  arrowFn.addFn = (s) => {
    return s * 3;
  }
}

arrowFn();

console.log(arrowFn.addFn(5));

arrowFn.sum = (g) => g + 5;

console.log(arrowFn.sum(5));



